# Array of counter in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I have to pass two arrays 
1) that are filled with 1000 int's between 0-100
2) that contains ten bins to sort the 1000 numbers.

How do I create the counter to sort numbers into ten bins such as 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-39, 40-49,50-59 and so on to 90-99...

Would it be with an if/else that sorts them? If so, how do I add values into each bin? Would it be something like this?

This is what I have so far:

```
          //initialize array of 1000 elements
          int[] numbers = new int[1000];
          int i = 0;
          //initialize array of 10 bins
          int[] bins = new int[10];

          void setup() {
              // Populate array with random number
              for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                 numbers[i] = ceil(random(0,99));
              }

           }

           //function that sorts random numbers into bins
           void counter(int[] numbers, int[] bins) {

           }
```

Comment: This is a bucket sort for integers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort

Comment: 0-100 is not evenly divisible by 10. make sure you handle the odd ranged bucket appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want every number from `numbers` in the right `bin` then I would use an array of 10 [ArrayLists](http://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) as the datastructure for your `bins`.

```
int[] numbers = new int[1000];
ArrayList[] bins = new ArrayList[10];

void setup() {
    for(int i = 0; i<bins.length; i++) {
        bins[i] = new ArrayList();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = floor(random(0,100));
    }
}

void counter(int[] numbers, ArrayList[] bins) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        bins[floor(float(numbers[i])/10.0)].add(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

You then get a bin with (for example the first bin consisting of numbers with values 0-9):

```
int sizeBin = bins[0].size();
for(int i=0; i<sizeBin; i++) {
    println(bins[0].get(i));
}
```

If you want the count of numbers in a bin you can get it with (again an example with the bin 0-9)

```
bins[0].size();
```

Comment: this seems like a very different approach then what i originally had... My only question is, with what you have provided where do you specify the conditions (boundaries) for each bin?

Comment: @theolc I calculate the right bin with the expression `floor(float(numbers[i])/10.0)` that I use to find the right index of the bin array. If the number is in the range 0-9 the expression will give 0, if it's in range 10-19 it will give 1... so I put every number at the right position into the array.

Comment: @theolc BTW: I just found a bug in the code when calculating your random numbers in `setup()`. `ceil(random(0,99))` Will give you numbers mostly in range 1-99 and not 0-99, because `ceil(floatnumber)` will become 0 only in the unlikely case when `floatnumber` is exactly 0. It gives you you 1 if `floatnumber` is a little bit larger than 0 and smaller than 1 (for way more cases than the exactly 1 to get 0) and so forth until 99. Better use `floor(random(0, 100))`.

Comment: this gives me errors. Im having such a pain with this piece :P "expecting DOT, found 'numbers'" lol :S   Sorry for the hassle, I appreciate your help very much! I am new to processing and am struggling with this

Comment: @theolc I had two errors. the first was a missing `}` after the for that fills the array `numbers` in your `setup`. The second error was at the line `int sizeBins = bins[0].size()`, I forgot the `;` at the end of the statement. I also put the initialisations of the arraylists for each bin inside the `setup` because that's the right place where all initialisations belong to and a good design.

Comment: @theolc Array of Arraylist is confusing I have to admit :). One Arraylist is similar to an array, but with the advantage that the size is not fixed and you can just add elements where you don't know the number of. You now need one Arraylist for every bin so you have an array of 10 arraylists. Understanding these 2 dimensional data structures is difficult in the beginning but they often help clarify your code and in this case it fits well to your problem. P.S. I fixed the problems I explained in the last comment in my post.

Comment: Amazing my friend. Thanks a ton for the input

Answer (score 2):

the simplest way a can think of is to use a for loop to cycle through the numbers[] and then a series of if statements to evaluate whether the number is <= 9 , <= 19 etc

```
    void counter(int[] numbers, int[] bins){
    int count = 0;
    int length = numbers.length;
    for(int i = 0; i< length; i++){
       if(numbers[i] <= 9){

          bins[count] = numbers[i];
          count++;
       }
    //and the same for 10-19 etc...
}
```

something like this maybe? not very eloquent but since the array is only 1000 elements it should suffice

Comment: That is actually what I was thinking... Thanks a lot! And am I passing the two arrays from setup into this function properly??? (I am new to processing)

Comment: actually a quick correction: bins[0] should say bins[count] , and yes it looks like you are passing in the parameters properly to me! mind you i haven't used processing in a while!

Comment: do i use bins[count] for each if statement? sorry for all the questions... I am a beginner with processing.

Comment: no i would set up a counter for each bin. for example countBin1, countBin2 etc. and only increment each counter when the corresponding bin has a value added to it